# unable to reference to .gs file within the google script created HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, backend

I am developing a web application using google script. I created a simple login page within the google script. However, I tried to reference the .js(.gs) to the button to sent out the login info but it keep showing 400 error. I know I probably do it the wrong way. I just don't know how to do it.

please help

```
  <script src="/login_click.gs"></script>///reference to the gs file
   .....
  <button type="submit" onclick="login()">Login</button>///the login button
```

Comment: You can't reference `.gs` files like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Client-to-server comms in GAS**

That's because .gs files are executed on the server and not on the client side. Apps script has its own implementation of asynchronous server calls via the `google.script.run` client API.

Using `google.script.run` is quite simple, you just call server-side functions by prepending their name like this `google.script.run.yourServerFunction(yourParameters)` and, if your server-side function has `return` statement, you can operate on the returned value via a callback client-side function passed to `withSuccessHandler()` method (if you want to pass anything client-side to callback function after server-side function finishes executing, you can do so via `withUserObject(dataToPass)` method call - just remember that the first argument of the success handler fucntion is always the value returned from server-side).

**Modified html**

In your case, a simple modification will do the trick (assuming you are calling a server-side `login()` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function success(fromServer,fromClient) {
    //doSomething on success;
  }

  function failure(error) {
    //doSomething on failure;
  }

  function login() {
    var myObject = ''; //add something to callback on success;

    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(success)
    .withFailureHandler(failure)
    .withUserObject(myObject)
    .login();
  }
</script>
```

**Useful links**

1. `google.script.run` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run);
2. Client-server communication [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication);

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one more question. Since I have more than one .gs file in my project, how dose server know which file to reference to?

Comment: Not at all! It's all handled by Google, don't worry about it - every .gs file is loaded on initialization in a global context, so you can reference any function anytime.